# How to store multiple text box values in array

Tags: php, html, arrays, textbox

Is it possible to store multiple textbox values in array, i have N number of textboxes

```
<input type="text" name="grade[]" id="grade" />
<input type="text" name="grade[]" id="grade" />
<input type="text" name="grade[]" id="grade" />
```

i tried this code to add all the text box value but it returns only the last text box value.

```
    $grade=$_POST['grade'];
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    $per=$grade[$i]*$grade[$i];
    echo $per;
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST['grade'])` to get an idea of what is being passed to your PHP.

Comment: how can you set same id to all text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides of starting on 0, it should finish on 2 if you have 3 text boxes.

```
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
{
  $per=$grade[$i]*$grade[$i];
  echo $per;
}
```

Or you could use the [array length](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) if you don't want to hardcode the number of iteractions. This should work:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($grade)-1;$i++)
{
  $per=$grade[$i]*$grade[$i];
  echo $per;
}
```

EDIT

This should work too and it's slightly cleaner (avoiding the -1) and using the [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($grade);$i++)
{
  echo pow($grade[$i], 2);
}
```

Comment: well `$i < 3` will stop at 2 just the same as `$i <= 2` will.

Comment: @Rawb92 I didn't see it when I wrote it, I saw it later, I just kept it in the question format with `<=`. Edited it. Also added the pow function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one...

```
<?php

    foreach ($_GET['grade'] as $grade){
        $per = $grade * $grade;
        echo $per;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$per='';
$grade=$_POST['grade'];
for($i=0;$i<count($grade);$i++)
{
    $per .=$grade[$i]*$grade[$i];
    $per .='<<>>';
}
 echo $per;
```

`count($grade)` is used for *n* no. of *textboxes*. You need to concatenate the values of variable in order to get the values of all the textboxes.